# Download CSV file in Google Chrome into a Python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, selenium-chromedriver

Hoping someone can help me with this. I am very new to using Python and the Selenium module. I am trying to download a CSV file from the following URL (https://www.nlrb.gov/search/case) and then assign that CSV file into a dataframe. See below for what I have tried. It gets as far as downloading it into my local computer, but I can't find a quick way to then load that file as a dataframe object.

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

#executes and opens Google Chrome #bestbrowser
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/Users/jmartinez/Downloads/chromedriver_win32 (2)/chromedriver.exe")

#waits for page to load
driver.implicitly_wait(25)

#page address
driver.get("https://www.nlrb.gov/search/case") #page address

#identifies and finds page element (the download button )
btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/main/div[3]/div/article/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/p[1]/a")
btn.click()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Apart from the above comment, an approach would be to use `pandas.read_csv(path_to_file)`, depending on the path, where the CSV is downloaded. It  will probably be stored at `"C:/Users/jmartinez/Downloads/chromedriver_win32 (2)/"` judging from your script. Check [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) for the pandas method.